typeorm ObjectLiteral where condition causes exception
I have a query that works in string format, but not in ObjectLiteral format:
  const queryBuilder = this.usersRepository.createQueryBuilder('user');
  const where = this.findQueryBuilder(options);

  const result = queryBuilder
    .leftJoinAndSelect('user.roles', 'role')
    .andWhere((qb) => {
      if (caslQueries.length > 0) {
        const [firstQuery, ...otherQueries] = caslQueries;
        qb.where(firstQuery);
        otherQueries.forEach((query) => qb.orWhere(query));
      }
    })
    .andWhere(where)
    .andWhere({ 'role.name': 'guest' })

this causes exception:

EntityPropertyNotFoundError: Property "role.name" was not found in "UserEntity". Make sure your query is correct.

but if I write the same code this way:
  const queryBuilder = this.usersRepository.createQueryBuilder('user');
  const where = this.findQueryBuilder(options);

  const result = queryBuilder
    .leftJoinAndSelect('user.roles', 'role')
    .andWhere((qb) => {
      if (caslQueries.length > 0) {
        const [firstQuery, ...otherQueries] = caslQueries;
        qb.where(firstQuery);
        otherQueries.forEach((query) => qb.orWhere(query));
      }
    })
    .andWhere(where)
    .andWhere('role.name = :role', { role: 'guest' })

this works without any problem. why?

try andWhere({ role: { name: 'guest' } })

it caused: EntityPropertyNotFoundError: Property "role" was not found in "UserEntity". Make sure your query is correct.
